# Do I have to specify the release version when running meteor build?

Tags: meteor

I would like to know if I have to specify the Meteor release version when I run `meteor build`. Or does `meteor build` take into consideration the Meteor release that the app is using (specified in `.meteor/release`?

I have been doing the following for my app:

```
meteor build --release 1.1.0.2
```

But I am not sure if this is necessary. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not obligatory, you can just run "meteor build ." which puts the bundled tar.gz into the current directory.